# Blender audio visualization - waveform line?

Tags: animation, modifiers, audio

Alright, followed all the relevant tutorials on Blender audio visualizations but they all involve either scaling/distorting objects with f curves or the bars type visual like this - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fK9Umxy1AAs

What Im trying to achieve is a line waveform like this:

[image]

Ive tried applying a cloud distortion to a plane, then slicing it and adding wireframe modifier, but this wasnt the same effect. In Aftereffects, you can increase the number of bars in your audio visualizer and generate this line effect.

Is this possible in Blender?

Comment: It is quite possible, but you'll need animation nodes to make it right.

Comment: Can you be more specific / provide a tutorial example?

Comment: I made this one a while back. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JqULEP1o5kA It uses AN to create curves and sound+math to animate them. You can modify the animation to produce the image you're after. It's 3 part, so if you're stuck, consider watching the first ones as well.